# Context cannot be cast to Activity (Android instrumented tests)

Tags: android, unit-testing, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am trying to test the Android app for multiple languages (over 40). Application behavior is configurable with Firebase Remote Config - parameters are set with device locale as Condition.

My test case requires a context that could be cast to Activity to properly execute production code:

```
mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(cacheExpiration)
            .addOnCompleteListener((Activity) context, new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
            {
                ...
            }
```

I have tried context defined in the following way:

```
Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
```

But it throws:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ContextImpl cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this?